# Sencha touch multiple data views in a container, scrolls horizontally and vertically

Tags: touch, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I have a navigation view and multiple data views inside it.
Everything works fine, but when i try to scroll any of the data views horizontally, the component also scrolls vertically( Please watch the video here: http://screencast.com/t/b9aWhgLdYI )
I want it to be such that when the dataview is scrolling, the vertical scroll should be stopped. But vertical scroll should happen when we scroll vertically out side the dataview.

Any ideas how we can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [directionLock](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.scroll.Scroller-cfg-directionLock) configuration. Example:

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    directionLock: true
}
```